# How can I add sonar on Github repo branch status check list?

Tags: git, github, sonarqube

I'd like to add sonar check on my Git repo status check on `master` branch. Below is the list of checks I can select. Currently only `buildkite` is listed there. How can I add sonar to the list?

[image]